# Match specific area code followed by numbers

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match 2 specific area codes followed by 7 digits. without any spaces or dashes.

This is what i got so far. Got it to match the area codes, but doesnt match the numbers after it

```
    /^\(?088|089\)(\d{7})$/i

088 - false
089 - false
0881234567 - true
0891234567 - true
081234567 - false
```

Comment: That `/i` will do you no good because numerals don't have case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\(?(?:088|089)\)?(\d{7})$
```

This should work fine for you.`)` was not optional.Have made it optional by adding `?` ahead of it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/14

Comment: hmm, it still only matches the area code `0881234567` dont match but `0891234567` does

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that if there is openning bracket `(` then there should be a closing one `)`. To prevent such cases:

```
(0891234567
088)1234567
```

Here is what I came up with: `^(\((088|089)\)|(088|089))\d{7}$`

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/bM4eD5/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(088|089)\d{7}/
```

This essentially says match any string starting with 088 or 089 and then followed by exactly 7 digits.